# Static IP address with wheezy 3.18.11+ and dhcpcd.conf

Tags: debian, raspbian-wheezy, static-ip

found some questions/answers depending on older versions of debian.
I'm using a newer one (3.18.11+) and I try to get dhcpcd with static IP addresses running.

**etc network interface**

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet manual
>
> allow-hotplug wlan0
>
> auto wlan0
>
> iface wlan0 inet manual
>
> wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

**dhcpcd.conf**

> interface eth0
>
> static ip_address=192.168.1.111/24
>
> static routers=192.168.1.1
>
> static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
>
> interface wlan0
>
> static ip_address=192.168.1.112/24
>
> static routers=192.168.1.1
>
> static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
>
> hostname
> ....
> default content

Result of this configuration with eth0 connected to the router

- ip address is 192.168.1.111/24  (dont understand the /24)
- can ping 192.168.1.111 from my pc
- **no internet connection, it seams something wrong with name resolution**
- I can open the router login mask from Raspberry with http://192.168.1.1

Comment: Finaly I found atyping mistake in the dhcpcd

Comment: Did you correct the typo in your question? What was it?

Comment: the IP address for static domain_name_servers was 192.16.1.1 instead of 192.168.1.1